# Why is その used here?

Tags: words, definitions, dictionary

I found [this definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/111179/meaning/m0u/%E9%A3%9F%E7%94%A8/) of 食用{しょくよう}:

> 食べ物として用いること。また、その食べ物。「食用になる」

Which I read as

> 食｛た｝べ物{もの}として用｛もち｝いること。また、その食｛た｝べ物｛もの｝。「食用{しょくよう}になる」

Meaning

> A thing that can be used as food. Also, that food. "To be edible"

I don't quite get what `その` could mean apart from `that`, but does that make sense here, as `edible` doesn't mean `food`, and according to [jisho](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%A3%9F%E7%94%A8), `食用` means

> for use as food; edible​

I am new to Japanese so forgive me if this is really obvious.

Comment: Just as a general tip, comparing two English words isn't a useful way to derive a Japanese definition. Yes, edible doesn't equal food, but while edible and food aren't even the same part of speech in English, 食用 and 食べ物 are both nouns in Japanese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding the first part of the definition.

> 食べ物として用いること。

means

> the use of something as a food.

The next bit specifies an alternate meaning that follows from a common use of the first meaning:

> また、その食べ物。

Means

> or, the food item [itself]

So 食用 refers to both the use of things as food and by extension food.

Thus,

食用 is either to make use of as food or something edible.

But to be edible is really 食用に適する

Comment: Dankie virmaior. After checking the definition of `として` (`as (i.e. in the role of); for (i.e. from the viewpoint of)`​) on jisho, your answer has made it very clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

> 食用：
>   食べ物として用いること。また、その食べ物。「食用になる」

The definition means as follows.

(1) 食用｛しょくよう｝とは、食べ物として用いること。
(2) 食用｛しょくよう｝とは、(1)で「**食べ物**として用いること」と定義した時の「**食べ物**」。
用例{ようれい}：**食用**になる。